# Running task multiple times with different values

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have a task that has to run multiple times for different environments. Also, I want the ability to choose which environment I run it for.

At first, I wanted dict to look like this but it makes no sense, and I'm stuck.

**'playbook.yaml'**

```
- name: dicttest
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    env1:   [
           { server: "server1", value1: "path1", value2: "path2" },
           { server: "server2", value1: "path3", value2: "path4" }
        ]

    env2:   [
           { server: "server3", value1: "path1", value2: "path2" },
           { server: "server4", value1: "path3", value2: "path4" },
           { server: "server5", value1: "path1", value2: "path2" }
        ]

  roles:
   - /home/user/ansible/roles/dict_test
```

**'dict_test.yml'**

```
- name: dict_test
  delegate_to: "{{server}}"
  ansible.builtin.command: "cp {{path1}} {{path2}}"
  loop:
    - "{{ lookup('vars', choose_ENV) }}"
```

I'm running this book with the:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e choose_ENV=env1
```

I want to choose the env and run it for every server in env with corresponding values. I know as it stands now it cant work, i dont know how to move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below shows how to iterate the lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "On {{ item.server }} copy {{ item.value1 }} to {{ item.value2 }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', choose_ENV) }}"
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    env1:
      - {server: server1, value1: path1, value2: path2}
      - {server: server2, value1: path3, value2: path4}
    env2:
      - {server: server3, value1: path1, value2: path2}
      - {server: server4, value1: path3, value2: path4}
      - {server: server5, value1: path1, value2: path2}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "On {{ item.server }} copy {{ item.value1 }} to {{ item.value2 }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', choose_ENV) }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e choose_ENV=env2

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server3', 'value1': 'path1', 'value2': 'path2'}) => 
  msg: On server3 copy path1 to path2
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server4', 'value1': 'path3', 'value2': 'path4'}) => 
  msg: On server4 copy path3 to path4
ok: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server5', 'value1': 'path1', 'value2': 'path2'}) => 
  msg: On server5 copy path1 to path2

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

- Optionally, create a dynamic group *choose_group* in the first play and use it in the second play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    env1:
      - {server: server1, value1: path1, value2: path2}
      - {server: server2, value1: path3, value2: path4}
    env2:
      - {server: server3, value1: path1, value2: path2}
      - {server: server4, value1: path3, value2: path4}
      - {server: server5, value1: path1, value2: path2}

  tasks:
  
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.server }}"
        groups: choose_group
        value1: "{{ item.value1 }}"
        value2: "{{ item.value2 }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', choose_ENV) }}"

- hosts: choose_group

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ value1 }} to {{ value2 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e choose_ENV=env2

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [add_host] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server3', 'value1': 'path1', 'value2': 'path2'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server4', 'value1': 'path3', 'value2': 'path4'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'server': 'server5', 'value1': 'path1', 'value2': 'path2'})

PLAY [choose_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [server3] => 
  msg: Copy path1 to path2
ok: [server4] => 
  msg: Copy path3 to path4
ok: [server5] => 
  msg: Copy path1 to path2

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server4: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server5: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

- Elegant option is the inventory plugin *constructed*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

Create the inventory

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-hosts
├── 02-constructed.yml
└── group_vars
    └── all
        └── env.yml
```

Put the data into the dictionary *env* in *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/group_vars/all/env.yml 
env:
  env1:
    - {server: server1, value1: path1, value2: path2}
    - {server: server2, value1: path3, value2: path4}
  env2:
    - {server: server3, value1: path1, value2: path2}
    - {server: server4, value1: path3, value2: path4}
    - {server: server5, value1: path1, value2: path2}
```

Create inventory files

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
use_vars_plugins: true
use_extra_vars: true
strict: true
compose:
  env_value1: env[choose_ENV]|items2dict(key_name='server', value_name='value1')
  env_value2: env[choose_ENV]|items2dict(key_name='server', value_name='value2')
groups:
  choose_group: inventory_hostname in env_value1
```

The inventory plugin will create the dictionaries *env_value1* and *env_value2*, and the group *choose_group*. The play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: choose_group

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: env_value1
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: env_value2
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ src }} to {{ dest }}"
      vars:
        src: "{{ env_value1[inventory_hostname] }}"
        dest: "{{ env_value2[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory -e choose_ENV=env2 pb.yml

PLAY [choose_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [server3] => 
  env_value1:
    server3: path1
    server4: path3
    server5: path1

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [server3] => 
  env_value2:
    server3: path2
    server4: path4
    server5: path2

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [server4] => 
  msg: Copy path3 to path4
ok: [server3] => 
  msg: Copy path1 to path2
ok: [server5] => 
  msg: Copy path1 to path2

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
server3: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server4: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server5: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thank you very much it works, I realized that I created a dictionary the wrong way